# Desestructuración de arreglos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Partiendo de que si estamos trabajando con un arreglo de elementos como el siguiente caso:

```
let datosVarios = [1, false, 'fruta', 'SO en español']
```

En el momento en que necesitemos asignar los valores de cada posición del arreglo a una variable, tenemos una opción de este modo para lograrlo; Lo que estamos haciendo en el código anterior es que a cada variable la igualamos con el valor de una posición específica del arreglo; recordando que los elementos de los arreglos parten de la posición 0

```
let posicionPrimera = datosVarios[0];
let posicionSegunda = datosVarios[1];
let posicionTercera = datosVarios[2];
let posicionCuarta = datosVarios[3];
```

Una vez realizado el paso anterior ya podemos mandar a imprimir cada una de las variables del segmento anterior y obtener el valor deseado

```
 console.log(posicionPrimera)
 console.log(posicionSegunda)
 console.log(posicionTercera)
 console.log(posicionCuarta)
```

> Sin embargo a partir de ECMSSCRIPT 6 existe el tema de
>   desestrcuturación el cual nos permite declarar un arreglo de variables
>   que después será igualado con el arreglo original de elementos

Como se adaptaría este ejemplo a trabajarlo por medio de la desestructuración de arreglos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sin embargo a partir de `ES6` tenemos a nuestro alcance lograr asignar los elementos de un arreglo a variables de un modo mas simple a través de la desestructuración

**Aquí el ejemplo**

```js
let datosVarios = [1, false, 'fruta', 'SO en español']

let [datoUno, datoDos, datoTres, datoCuatro] = datosVarios

console.log(datoUno)
console.log(datoDos)
console.log(datoTres)
console.log(datoCuatro)
```

**Aquí la explicación**

1. Tenemos un arreglo con datos múltples contenidos en el mismo
2. declaramos un arreglo que por dentro contiene la misma cantidad de variables que elementos tiene el arreglo
3. El arreglo de variables recién declarado lo igualamos al arreglo original
4. Ahora podemos imprimir cada uno de los valores del arreglo original, por cada variable que obtenemos del nuevo arreglo declarado, sin necesidad de indicar la posición en la que se encuentra dicho valor

**¿Qué ocurre si declaro en el arreglo de variables una de mas y luego la mando a imprimir?**

Como tendrás una variable declarada de mas, que no tiene con que valor de arreglo original igualarse, entonces al imprimirla marcará como `undefined`

**Aquí el ejemplo**

```js
let datosVarios = [1, false, 'fruta', 'SO en español']

let [datoUno, datoDos, datoTres, datoCuatro, datoCinco] = datosVarios

console.log(datoUno)
console.log(datoDos)
console.log(datoTres)
console.log(datoCuatro)
console.log(datoCinco)
```

*Como se puede apreciar entre el código escrito en la pregunta y el código escrito en la respuesta resalta lo siguiente:*

> 1. No necesito acceder a las posiciones del `array` donde se encuentran contenidos los valores
> 2. En lugar de acceder a las posiciones del `array` y asignarselos a cada `variable`, declaro el arreglo de variables que a su misma vez
>      igualo con con el arreglo original que contiene los elementos